# reducing pipe size between well pump and pressure tank!

Tags: water

I am replacing my leaking well pressure tank which is sitting next to my well. It has a 1 inch inlet to the tank and a 3/4 line to my house roughly forty feet away. Is there any good reason why I cannot bypass the old pressure tank, put in a reducer and tie on to the line to the house and set the new tank in my cellar where the existing 3/4 line enters the piping system? My well pump is submerged about 80 feet.

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine - in some ways better than the old setup. Ideally you'd maintain 1 inch, but practically speaking it won't make enough difference to notice over that distance.

Comment: I would agree with the pressure tank closer to the point of use the size won't be a problem.

Comment: Well---it would save the trouble of digging up the old tank and setting a new one underground. All my piping runs thru the cellar, is not wrapped, has never frozen (we just had about a week of below freezing temps). I don't know why the pressure tank wasn't set in the basement to begin with.